# How to get a row from result of Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Query in Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am using `Ecto.Adapters.SQL` 
I have this query below

```
query = "select c.name, c.email from clients c where c.id in (1,2,3)"
```

Then I put the query in my `Repo`

```
result = SQL.query(Automessages.Repo, query , [])
```

After that I got this result(Map) with 3 rows

```
{:ok,
 %Mariaex.Result{columns: ["name", "email"], connection_id: nil,
  last_insert_id: nil, num_rows: 3,
  rows: [["Ana Silva", "name0@gmail.com"],
   ["Farias de melo", "name1@mail.net"],
   ["João da costa", "name3@hotmail.com"]]}}
```

My question is how to get only the rows?

```
[["Ana Silva", "name0@gmail.com"],
   ["Farias de melo", "name1@mail.net"],
   ["João da costa", "name3@hotmail.com"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching to extract the rows:

```
{:ok, %{rows: rows}} = SQL.query(Automessages.Repo, qry , [])
# rows is now [["Ana Silva", ...], ...]
```

Note that this will throw a `MatchError` if the pattern matching fails. If you don't want that, you can use `case` to handle it:

```
case SQL.query(Automessages.Repo, qry , []) do
  {:ok, %{rows: rows}} ->
    # rows is available here
  {:error, error} ->
    # some error occurred
end
```